# Check every element in a list type property in defining a type

Tags: typescript

I want to make the [intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) type of the properties of two types below.

```
interface DOMRectReadOnly {
  readonly width: number;
  readonly height: number;
  readonly left: number;
  readonly top: number;
  readonly right: number;
  readonly bottom: number;
  ...
}

interface StyleProperties {
  size: ["width", "height"];
  start: ["left", "top"],
  end: ["right", "bottom"];
}
```

by making it as below.

```
type DOMRectStyleProperties = {
  [P in keyof StyleProperties]:
    (StyleProperties[P][0] | StyleProperties[P][1]) extends keyof DOMRectReadOnly
    ? P
    : never
}[keyof StyleProperties];
// The result is "size" | "start" | "end"
```

But how can I deal with a general case like when there is too many elements in a list of `StyleProperties`? I won't be able to make the `(StyleProperties[P][0] | StyleProperties[P][1])` part infinite like `(StyleProperties[P][0] | StyleProperties[P][1] | StyleProperties[P][2] | ...)`. And also the number of elements can be different depending on the list like below.

```
interface StyleProperties {
  size: ["width", "height"];
  start: ["left", "top", "x", "y"],
  end: ["right", "bottom"];
}
```

**Solution dealing with tuples, including some corrections from @willis' answer**

```
// Note that readonly is added
type First<T extends readonly any[]> = T['length'] extends 0 ? never : T[0];
// Note that readonly is added
type Shift<T extends readonly any[]> = T extends readonly [any, ...infer rest] ? rest : never;

// Note that readonly is added to type 'Tuple'
type PickTuple<Matcher extends any, Tuple extends readonly any[], Accumulation extends any[] = []>
  = Tuple['length'] extends 0
  // Note that it returns never depending on the length of the Accumulation. See the usage below.
  ? Accumulation['length'] extends 0 ? never : Accumulation
  : First<Tuple> extends Matcher
  ? PickTuple<Matcher, Shift<Tuple>, [...Accumulation, First<Tuple>]>
  // Note the third argument is never as the intention of my question is picking only tuples whose elements all match the Matcher
  : never;
```

And the usage is

```
/**
 * Note that StyleProperties is a value not a type so 'as const' is added
 * See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66078924/10694438
 */
export const StyleProperties = {
  size: ["width", "height"] as const,
  start: ["left", "top"] as const,
  end: ["right", "bottom"] as const
};

/**
 * To pick the keys of tuples whose elements all match the Matcher(keyof DOMRectReadOnly in this case),
 * setting a tuple's type as never or as the key
 * and extracting the values by {...}[keyof typeof StyleProperties] are needed.
 */
type DOMRectStyleProperties = {
  [P in keyof typeof StyleProperties]: PickTuple<keyof DOMRectReadOnly, typeof StyleProperties[P]> extends never ? never : P
}[keyof typeof StyleProperties];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to iterate through a tuple type, and for that you'll want to be able to recursively process the elements of the tuple one by one. And for that, you'll want some way of getting at the first element in the tuple, and then some way of removing it from the tuple:

```
type Shift<T extends any[]> = T extends [infer _, ...infer Rest] ? [...Rest] : never;
type First<T extends any[]> = T['length'] extends 0 ? never : T[0];
```

Once you have those pieces, you can set up a recursive type to filter the keys that you want from the tuple:

```
type GrabDOMKeys<T extends any[], Acc extends any[] = []> = T['length'] extends 0 ? 
  Acc :
  First<T> extends keyof DOMRectReadOnly ?
    GrabDOMKeys<Shift<T>, [...Acc, First<T>]> : GrabDOMKeys<Shift<T>, Acc>;
```

This would allow you to filter out the properties you need:

```
type Example = GrabDOMKeys<["width", "height", "banana", "left"]>;
type Example2 = GrabDOMKeys<StyleProperties['size']>
```

Finally, this should let you grab the DOM properties you want:

```
type DomProps = {
  [P in keyof StyleProperties]: GrabDOMKeys<StyleProperties[P]>
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIHkCyAlCCy5wAm6IANgJ7IDeAUMslBMQPblUDuwRYAFgFzIQAVwC2AI2gBueo2ZE2lZLwjAA5rzCCRE6bKat2yMhBhahYyVBkMDCo2BYAHbZb235iqlHWbXu631PI3EWMEdRfysZAF9aWlBIWEQUAGUwChMABShnaDBgCABnGlki4AAvCEEAbQAiLh5eOoAaZDqVXzBW9pAw5DhkPlA1HrqnXKc6gF0bZCKwOChzepMzMccptrrQ8JZRGZbZCBAiWrqfDW7t3YiZ2PiMpzTeYDMAHgAVZAgAD0hTiU4CAKDVpgA+ZAAXmQ3z+AKIJRqoBg0GQAH02gA6HEotG4BbTZAAfmQNRxWIJYCJ2ggADc9E8UAAxYBQBZfH7-E6IgYgsGQmGfGoAchMIDUfBFRPhPJKAAYSUJ6WjBML5bNHhRnsgAOJQODiDCYADSEAoRU5ssBfNB0zaAEEEAguQigfyiTCBdDYaLxZLeNLXXLkIrSU6XfxZKz2WAvpDrbyANbmlgwNBYXD4QgkIzE2QMfWG41mi3vVKvD6fcFtck4iNtGMc6sQ5CCItGrCly0Vt5x6uO53gqTILU6gCivzgoicJh9HZL5st9UafDGnSuY3EwJ3YzW3QhMiZyEn09nEAATPODZ3TUvyxlspN8oUiqLylVpeCxyhUPscs4JQwnQDA1FkyCgMgKYUGmyDpJkEAAc8yyvtM7Y3ouZbwU+eQocUYEQrQMRSEAA)

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I could solve the problem. But you need to change `: GrabDOMKeys<Shift<T>, Acc>;` to `: never;`, as I only wanted to pick tuples whose elements all match the keyof DOMRectReadOnly.