# 'keyof typeof value' makes different type result compared to 'keyof interface'

Tags: typescript

I initially defined [the intersection type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) of type `DOMRectReadOnly` and `StyleProperties` like below which results type `"size" | "start" | "end"`.

```
interface StyleProperties {
    size: ["width", "height"];
    start: ["left", "top"],
    end: ["right", "bottom"];
}

export const StyleProperties: StyleProperties = {
    size: ["width", "height"],
    start: ["left", "top"],
    end: ["right", "bottom"]
};

type DOMRectStyleProperties = {
  [P in keyof StyleProperties]:
    (StyleProperties[P][0] | StyleProperties[P][1]) extends keyof DOMRectReadOnly
    ? P
    : never
}[keyof StyleProperties];
```

But I want to remove `interface StyleProperties` part and replace its uses with `typeof StyleProperties` like below, but it results type `never`.

```
export const StyleProperties = {
    size: ["width", "height"],
    start: ["left", "top"],
    end: ["right", "bottom"]
};

type DOMRectStyleProperties = {
  [P in keyof typeof StyleProperties]:
    (typeof StyleProperties[P][0] | typeof StyleProperties[P][1]) extends keyof DOMRectReadOnly
    ? P
    : never
}[keyof typeof StyleProperties];
```

What's wrong in my usage of `typeof` keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your use of `typeof`. The issue is that the types that typescript is able to infer for `StyleProperties` is less strict than you'd like:

```
const StyleProperties = {
    size: ["width", "height"],
    start: ["left", "top"],
    end: ["right", "bottom"]
};
type Example = typeof StyleProperties;
```

If you look at this, you'll see that these properties are now `string[]` rather than typed tuples. If you tell typescript that these are constants and won't change, you should get the type you want:

```
const StyleProperties = {
    size: ["width", "height"] as const,
    start: ["left", "top"] as const,
    end: ["right", "bottom"] as const,
};
type Example = typeof StyleProperties;
```

And with the correct type, using `typeof` should do what you want!